# Angular reset form when signal is true using effect()

Tags: angular, signals, zonejs, angular-signals

I'm wondering if I'm using signals correctly in the following use case. I have a form, which needs to be reset when the success signal is true. I've done so using an effect. However the Angular docs are not entirely clear about this yet (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/signals#effects)).

**Would you consider this a valid use of an effect? **

```
protected success = this.store.selectSignal(fakeFeatureName.selectSuccess);

constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.success()) {
        this.form.reset();
      }
    });
  }
```

Angular docs currently lists this a valid options to use an effect:

**Effects are rarely needed in most application code**, but may be useful in specific circumstances. Here are some examples of situations where an effect might be a good solution:

- Logging data being displayed and when it changes, either for analytics or as a debugging tool
- Keeping data in sync with window.localStorage
- Adding custom DOM behavior that can't be expressed with template syntax
- Performing custom rendering to a , charting library, or other third party UI library

BUT
Avoid using effects for propagation of state changes

Answer (score 0):

If in the variable's description, you use words related to time, then you need an observable, not a signal. Signals have no "time" dimension.
I'll quote my [tweet](https://twitter.com/eugeniyoz/status/1732441738399138140) here:

**If the role of a variable can be described as conditions, then you need Angular Signals:**

- "if this variable has this value, then display this list"
- "if this variable has this value, this button is disabled"

As you can see, Signals are great for the template control flow.

**If the description of a variable's role includes words, related to time, you need Observables:**

- "when the cursor moves..."
- "wait for the file uploading event and then..."
- "every time this event happens, do this..."
- "until this event..."
- "for N seconds ignore..."

Signals are great for application state management, and I recommend you use signals in the templates of your components.

But you can see that Observables are still quite useful and helpful in Angular - unlike Signals, they have a "time" dimension and "completeness".